# Lifetime of data associated with std::current_exception

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
std::exception_ptr eptr{ std::current_exception() };
const char* msg = 0;
try {
    if (eptr != std::exception_ptr{}) {
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
} catch(const std::exception& ex) {
    msg = ex.what();
}
```

Can I use `msg` outside of `catch`? In other words does `ex` references to the same exception instance as `eptr`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: I would not, because `ex` and `eptr` (might ?) reference different exceptions. (see edit: it might be guaranteed, but the standard is unclear enough that I would avoid relying on it)

The lifetime of exceptions is ruled by **§15.1 [except.throw]**, and specifically:

> 4/ The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified way, except as noted in §3.7.4.1. If a handler exits by rethrowing, control is passed to another handler for the same exception. **The exception object is destroyed after either the last remaining active handler for the exception exits by any means other than rethrowing, or the last object of type `std::exception_ptr` (§18.8.5) that refers to the exception object is destroyed, whichever is later.** In the former case, the destruction occurs when the handler exits, immediately after the destruction of the object declared in the *exception-declaration* in the handler, if any. In the latter case, the destruction occurs before the destructor of `std::exception_ptr` returns. The implementation may then deallocate the memory for the exception object; any such deallocation is done in an unspecified way. [ *Note:* a thrown exception does not propagate to other threads unless caught, stored, and rethrown using appropriate library functions; see §18.8.5 and §30.6. *—end note* ]

However, you also need to take into account the previous paragraph:

> 3/ Throwing an exception copy-initializes (§8.5, §12.8) a temporary object, called the exception object. The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler (§15.3). [...]

Thus, what happens in your case:

- `eptr` is initialized to point to the current exception in flight, guaranteeing this exception lives at least as long as it does
- `ex` is initialized to reference **a copy** of the exception pointed to by `eptr`
- when the catch clause ends, **the copy** dies
- `msg` was pointing into the copy, and thus is left dangling... unless both copy and original shared the same message under the covers.

The only way to guarantee that an exception lives long enough for your purpose is to create a `std::exception_ptr`, directly.

**EDIT** Ralph Tandetzky brough to my attention that **§18.8.5 [propagation]** says:

> 7/ [...] [ *Note:* if `rethrow_exception` rethrows the same exception object (rather than a copy), concurrent access to that rethrown exception object may introduce a data race. Changes in the number of `exception_ptr` objects that refer to a particular exception do not introduce a data
>   race. *—end note* ]

Which suggests that in the following paragraph:

> ```
> [[noreturn]] void rethrow_exception(exception_ptr p);
> ```
>
> 9/ *Requires:* `p` shall not be a null pointer.
>
> 10/ *Throws:* the exception object to which `p` refers.

the *Throws* clause should not be interpreted as some kind of `throw *p;`, but instead *could* have the same behavior as `throw;` (re-throwing the very same instance, not a copy). However, since there is a *if* in paragraph 7, it seems it might be a copy too...

---

Note: interestingly experiments suggests that [the underlying object may be shared](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/889051aace1885ff)... which contradicts my reading of the standard; I don't quite understand how *copy-initializes* could be interpreted differently though.

Comment: Your answer appears to be wrong according to support.exception.propagation (18.8.5 as of N3797). There `rethrow_exception()` is specified to rethrow the exception object the pointer is referring to (not the copy!). `current_exception()` may or may not create a copy. Interestingly, in paragraph 7 it states: *Note:* if rethrow_exception rethrows the same exception object (rather than a copy), concurrent access to that rethrown exception object may introduce a data race. Weirdly according to spec this assumption is always met. (No "if" is necessary.) Kerrek SBs answer seems to be correct.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: Ah, thanks, paragraph 7 would explain the observed behavior better. So `rethrow_exception` would have a specific behavior, and behave like a `throw;` and not like a `throw e;`. I find the: "*Throws:* the exception object to which `p` refers." statement ambiguous though since `throw` is specified to copy :x

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: I edited my answer, however it is still unclear to me. I find the wording of both 7 and 10 to be highly confusing. 7 implies there might be a copy (why, where) and 10 uses the wording *Throws* where `throw e;` is specified to create a copy while `throw;` is specified not to... In the case of gcc, in one experiment, there was no copy; but that's hardly what I would call a proof.

Comment: That's what I meant. From paragraph 10 I would read that there is no copy made. A copy can only be made when calling `std::current_exception()`.

Answer (score 6):

The description of `rethrow_exception` says:

> *Throws:* the exception object to which `p` refers.

So the thrown object is the same one to which the pointer refers. The pointer may or may not refer to the original "current exception", because `current_exception` might make a copy of the exception object, but that's irrelevant to your question.

So yes, the exception object that you rethrow is the same one that's owned by `eptr` and thus remains alive as long at least as long as that pointer owns it.

Comment: `eptr` exception is alive with all its assosiated data but it's not the case for its copy. It is unsafe to use result of `ex.what()` if it's a copy of original `eptr`

Comment: @AlexT: Don't confuse the exception object with the managing smart pointer.

Comment: by "`eptr` exception" I ment "instance of exception object referenced by `eptr`". Another related question is whether initial std::current_exception should point to the same exception instance as that taken in `catch(...)` block: `try { std::rethrow_exception(eptr1); } catch(...) { const std::exception_ptr eptr2{std::current_exception()}; //is eptr2 == to eptr1?`. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexT: As I said, `std::current_exception` is allowed to make copies, but `std::rethrow_exception` is not.

Comment: Let me take timeout to dig it by myself - I thought this question has simple answer.